# Turn off Windows 10 smart quotes

Tags: windows-10, input

Some Windows 10 modern UI apps (at least Mail and Calendar) have adopted the bad habit of MS office to replace simple quotes with "pretty" quotes during input.

[image]

In office you can disable it in the options, but I looked through all Windows 10 settings (and the old control panel as well), but I can't find it.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour? I have the feeling that this behaviour only affects multiline text boxes in modern UI apps.

<sub>Note: It is quite possible that this behaviour is specific to the german input language.</sub>

Comment: In this case it's the Windows Mail app, as well as the calendar app. There are no options to turn it off. I have the impression that it's a feature of the text input field in modern UI apps.

Comment: Have you tried these - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445325/how-to-disable-auto-pairing-of-quotes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @user52599, but this is related only to the US input language. I have only the german input language. I already looked through the language related options.

Comment: Try turning off spellcheck in Mail: https://superuser.com/questions/1137145/how-to-disable-autocorrect-in-windows-10-mail

Comment: You may have turned it on accidently - `Ctrl + Shift + ' (apostrophe) Activate smart quotes` and do it again to turn off. This is standard behaviour of Windows' RichEdit control (used by wordpad compared to notepad's edit control).

Comment: @Mark that doesn't make any difference. The behaviour doesn't occur in WordPad, only in modern UI apps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal, but you can hit ctrl-z just after Mail has replaced the standard quote with a smart one.